# Interacting with deeply nested radio buttons in Capybara

Tags: html, css, xpath, radio-button, capybara

Recently, I've come across a radio button that seems to be so deeply nested that Capybara simply cannot interact with it.

## Example of the HTML:

```
<div …>
   <div …>
      <div …>
         <ul …>
            <li …>
               <label …>
                 <div …>
                    <input id=”radio1” name=”Section1.Radio1” type=”radio”></input>
                    <label …> </label>  
                 </div>
               </label>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are about 10 more levels of depth beyond this that I've omitted before hitting the  tag.

### What I've Tried

I’ve tried a combination of capybara’s finders including: **choose, click_on, find, find_first**; all with various xpath and css combinations.  These all result in a generic error “Element not found”.  The xpaths and css I use are tested in Chrome and FF developer tools with no issues.
The only break I’ve gotten is with the ‘all’ finder.

```
all(:css, #id_name).first
```

This seems to result in a found object, when I add ‘click’:

```
all(:css, #id_name).first.click
```

I receive an error in Capybara **'undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)'**

Maybe I should go in a different direction.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `#choose` method that Capybara provides.  From the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions:choose):

> Find a radio button and mark it as checked. The radio button can be
>   found via name, id or label text.

so in your instance:

`page.choose('radio1')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's not working.  I updated my post above.

Comment: What's generating the radio button out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
first(:css, 'radio1').click
```